# Route for appointment locations based on distance and appointment time

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra, traveling-salesman

I want to develop an algorithm which taken in location and appointment times of different places a person needs to visit starting from his/her office. After completing all the appointment visits, this person must come back to the office. I want to plan a route for him/her that covers all the appointments in such a way that:

- He/Her travels the minimum distance
- The route construction taken into the account the appointment time. That is, appointment time should take priority over the distance between two locations when deciding which location should be visited next.

My question is open-ended. I know that if I just want to take the distance into account for constructing a route, this fits directly into the Traveling Salesman Problem. But, I also want to take the appointment time into account. I am new to graphs and I was wondering if this problem fits better into some other algorithm that I am not aware of. If not, I am looking for suggestions for modifying the TSP algorithm to consider these two parameters.

While thinking about this problem, I thought about how I would implement Dijkstra for finding a route. I am aware that this is a completely different problem than TSP. But, how do you think I can combine two parameters(distance and appointment time) to compare two nodes in my priority queue ADT for Dijkstra.

Probably, these two problems require different questions but I feel that this is a common problem. I am looking for suggestions about approaching these graph problems where there are two factors that need to be considered. How can I take two parameters and combine them into one, so that I can compare two nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you need to be on time for an appointment and not early, then you can start with a fully connected graph and then remove edges between nodes if they are too far apart, according to their appointment times.

For example if Node A has a time of 10:00 and node B has a time of 11:00 and the shortest distance between them is over 1 hour, then you can trim this edge.

This also includes trimming edge(A,B) if Node A has an appointment time after node B.

After this you only need to find the shortest hamiltonian cycle - which is TSP.

Edit: To answer your question directly: There is no need to account for the appointment time in the TSP part of the problem. Simply setup the graph (as described above) and then run a TSP algorithm.